# How to automate "run asp.net website" from command line?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, batch-file, iis, iis-express

Right now, I do the following manual steps to run an ASP.NET website on my PC:

1. Open Visual Studio and the project inside it
2. Press Ctrl+F5 which:

   1. Builds the solution
   2. Runs IIS express
   3. Opens a browser

How to write a batch file that does the same thing? The last step (opening a browser) is optional but at least I need to build the project and start it on IIS express (or whatever is configured in the project file).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the visual studio command line you could do the following:

```
devenv "C:\path\FooSolution.sln" /run
```

[**MSDN Devenv Command Line Switches Reference**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx)

Wrapping this all up into a batch file (assuming VS 2012) it would become:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" 
devenv "C:\path\FooSolution.sln" /Run
```

**Update**

To run this outside of Visual Studio with IIS Express you would use the following commands:

```
msbuild.exe "C:\path\FooSolution.sln" 
iisexpress /path:c:\path\fooapp\ /port:666
start "" http://localhost:666
```

Please note there are many configuration options for both msbuild and iisexpress command. You will need to tailor them to suite your needs.

**[Running IIS Express from the Command Line](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line)**

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Visual Studio actually starting up? I guess the build could be done by MSBuild so if there is a way to launch IIS Express with the result silently, that would be perfect.

Comment: @hutchonoid Is there a way to add projects to my solution from the command line? Thanks in advance :)