# Run Asp.Net 5.2 From Command Line

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Really sorry for bad screenshot. My solution just running well with visual studio 2017 and iisExpress. Is there any way i can look the "command list" when i press that "Google Chrome" button ? so i can run my solution with iisexpress from command line.

My machine just have a small amount of RAM (+- 4GB). I plan to change visual studio with gvim and exec some "build command" whenever i change the code. Adding a RAM is not an option for current situation.

`Environment: .NET 4.6.2, Asp.NET MVC 5.2.3, Win7 32bit HomeEdition`

[image: part of visual studio 2017]

Comment: Simply point an IIS Express at your project directory and browse the proper URL with Chrome? If I think what you mean by "debug" is "run the application", because with no debugger attached there's nothing to debug.

Comment: Thanks for fast response @CodeCaster , yes i need to "build" all the project within my solution and run it with debug mode. Can i simply run iisexpress ?

Comment: No, you need Visual Studio for that, especially the "run it with debug mode". How are you going to debug without a debugger? Do you want to call msbuild from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your help pointing me "msbuild" @CodeCaster, My question is similar to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692172/how-to-automate-run-asp-net-website-from-command-line