# How to start a MVC Application from a Console Appication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have written a Console Application that uses OAuth2.0 for API-Call-Authorization. The token generation process is seperated from the API calls and therefore written in a seperate MVC-App. I would like to call said MVC from my console Application so that I do not have to start the MVC manually every time I want to generate a Token for the Authorization. Any Tipps on how to do this ?

Comment: Similar question was asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692172/how-to-automate-run-asp-net-website-from-command-line

Comment: @ColbyBoren I am not trying to write a Batch file. I am trying to implement a call to an MVC Application into my console Application in order to call it automatically when needed.